# How to hide keyboard of type .phonePad using SwiftUI for applications that support multiple scenes?

Tags: swift, textfield, swiftui, dismiss, ios13

I want to dismiss keyboard of type `.phonePad` after editing if finished or  when user taps outside of `TextField`

```swift
TextField("Phone Number", text: $call.phoneNumber).keyboardType(.phonePad)
```

How can i do this in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0):

All I do is put a button on the view controller and make it full screen. In the Document Outline, move it up so it is behind any text fields, buttons, etc and as an action use view.endEditting(true).

Comment: I don't understand your solution. Can you please give some code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Ended with this solution:

```swift
TextField("Phone", text: $callSettings.phoneNumber)

                .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                .onTapGesture {
                    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                                       .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
                                       .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
                                       .compactMap({$0})
                                       .first?.windows
                                       .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
                    keyWindow!.endEditing(true)

             }
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using so convoluted approach witch connectedScenes filter map ... instead just access keyWindow as 
            UIApplication.shared.windows.first{$0.isKeyWindow }?.endEditing(true)